# Javascript ifDefined helper method?

Tags: javascript

Is there a helper method, or similar, in Javascript for `isDefined`?  I just found this in a utility file I inherited:

```
'use strict';

var me = {
    ifDefined           : ifDefined,
    ifDef               : ifDefined,
    isDefined           : isDefined,
    isDef               : isDefined,
};

function isDefined (value) {
    return (typeof value != 'undefined');
}
function ifDefined (value, defaultValue) {
    return isDefined(value) ? defaultValue : value;
}

module.exports = me;
```

It appears the author is using it to have a shorthand method for the `typeof` check:

```
environment.u = isDef(envInfo.u, environment.u);
environment.x = isDef(envInfo.x, environment.x);
environment.s = isDef(envInfo.s, environment.s);
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? The `typeof` operator _is_ how you check if an identifier is defined or not. Are you hoping for a different built-in? What is wrong with these functions?

Comment: I'm asking IF such a shorthand method exists.  It appears the author created this file so he would not have `typeof` calls in his code.

Comment: Then no, there is no built-in `isDefined`. Try searching MDN next time: [Standard built-in objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects), [Expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a helper method, or similar, in Javascript for `isDefined`?

No, there exists no builtin function for this.

Just using `value !== undefined` or `value != null` is short enough, it didn't warrant an extra utility function. The only native "typechecking" methods I am aware of are `Array.isArray`, `isNaN` and `isFinite` (and their `Number.is…` equivalents).

Answer (score 1):

There is not.  If I **had** to do this, I wouldn't create a utility file for it.  You could save just as much space in your code by using a shorthand **variable** and the ternary operator:

```
var udef = undefined;

environment.u = envInfo.u == udef ? environment.u : envInfo.u;
environment.x = envInfo.x == udef ? environment.x : envInfo.x;
environment.s = envInfo.s == udef ? environment.s : envInfo.s;
```

For comparison:

Answer (score 0):

What this function seems to do is check if a value is undefined, and if it is, returns a default value. Otherwise it returns the original value. The name is somewhat misleading, and I don't believe there is anything directly built in to JavaScript that mimics the functionality of your `ifDefined` function.

If what you are looking for is to simply check if something is defined or not, using `typeof` is unnecessary - you can simply compare against the global `undefined` object:

```
var x;
if(x !== undefined){
    console.log('this will not run');
}
else{
    console.log('this will run');
}
```

Some extra reading, if interested: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined